# integral matrix of order p

Tags: nt.number-theory, linear-algebra

Hi everyone

Let $p$ be a prime number. I am interested to classify $\{ A\in {\rm GL}_{p-1}(\mathbb{Z}): {\rm ord}(A)=p \}$ up to conjugacy. One reason to consider this problem is its relation to class number of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$, more precisely one can show  $|\{ [A]\in {\rm GL}_{p-1}(\mathbb{Z}): {\rm ord}(A)=p \}|=h(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p))$ where $[A]$ is denoted for conjugacy class.

It seems  $\{ [A]\in {\rm GL}_{p-1}(\mathbb{Z}): {\rm ord}(A)=p \}$ is more easier to study than class number of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$. At least its seems is easier to show is finite without invoking Geometry of number which shows  $h(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p))$ is finite. For example Borel and Harish-Chandra theorem ("Arithmetic subgroups of algebraic groups") shows that this set should be finite, (they proved much more general theorem which implies this, I have never read that paper so I don't know their proof for the general theorem. So they might reduce it to class number or some adelic version of class number).

Ok, now is time to ask a question. Is there any paper considering this problem which give us some finiteness theorem (beside Borel and Harish-Chandra paper)?

Comment: Who is this Borel-Hirsh-chandra of whom you speak?

Comment: @Igor Rivin: I typed it wrongly. I meant Armand Borel and Harish-chandra. 

Comment: @M.B.: It was Harish-Chandra with a capital "C". Right? There were also papers by Grunewald and Segal and by Sarkisyan, proving the Hasse local-global principle.

Comment: @Mark: I corrected Harish-Chandra, thank you. 

Comment: I agree that the end result is arguably cleaner but I think that if you trace the prehistory of the Borel/Harish-Chandra result then it has its origin in one of the early proofs of finiteness of class number.

Comment: For $p=3$, using the fact that $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ is the amalgamated product of the cyclic group of order 6 with the cyclic group of order 4 over the cyclic group of order 2, you get that there is a unique conjugacy class of elements of order 3 in $GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$. But I'm sure you know this already.

Comment: You might know all this already, but just in case: the eigenvalues of any matrix of order $p$ must be $p$th roots of unity. In addition one of them must be not equal to 1, or else the matrix doesn't have actually order $p$. If a matrix with integer entries has any primitive $p$th root of unity as an eigenvalue, then it has all primitive $p$th roots of unity as eigenvalues. Since the matrices we're discussing here have size $p-1$, that implies that each primitive $p$th root of unity is an eigenvalue of multiplicity 1. All such matrices are conjugate over the complex numbers, at least.

Comment: @Greg Martin: Nice comment, thank you. One might extend your observation and deduce this general theorem. Let $A,B\in M_n(F)$, where $F$ is a field, with same irreducible minimal polynomial of degree n, then $A$ and $B$ are conjugate over F. As you know, Question would be much more delicate if we want to consider the conjugacy class over $\mathbb{Z}$. I think Torsten Ekedahl's remark is very interesting, it seems this type of question was motivation for Borel and Harich-Chandra.         

Comment: Following Greg Martin, such matrices are in fact conjugate over the rationals, since their rational canonical form is the companion matrix of the $p$th cyclotomic polynomial.  This is therefore a question of how conjugacy differs over rationals versus integers.